# Erro de session em Java

Tags: java, session, aplicação-web, exceção

Tenho os seguintes métodos :

```
public void delete(Class c, int id) throws SQLException {        
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Object ob = this.getById(c, id);
        session.delete(ob);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        throw new SQLException(c.getName() + " - Não foi possivel excluir o registro!");
    }
}

public Object getById(Class c, Integer id) {
    Object session =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(c, id);
    return session;
}
```

Porém a seguinte exception é retornada:  **Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions**

O que devo fazer ?

Comment: Ter várias sessões é custoso, vamos dizer assim. Esse erro ocorre porque duas sessões estão abertas ao mesmo tempo. Você pode: Criar uma única sessão e repassar ao seu(s) DAO(s) ou utilizar um trecho `try/finally` para fechar a sessão após realizar as transações.

Comment: Me parece que o objeto Session não é comum às duas funções, a partir do momento que vc o declara dentro da delete. Tente pegar a session em uma variável private de classe e não dentro da função.

Comment: é possível colocar mais informações?